# Dependency Injection / duplication of service added as Singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.2

I can't figure out why my dependency injection is not working as expected, when my controller is hit the constructor of `MyFirstService` is being hit again and therefore I am hitting a different cancellation token to the one I wish to be when calling the `StopFeeds()` method.

I have tried to add the controller in as a singleton and use the controller's `StartFeed()` method to instantiate the class but no matter what I do with DI (general ctor DI, explicit property assignment, `[FromServices]` and even directly passing in the service collection) when I hit stop feeds it will create another instance of `MyFirstService` ... Any ideas?

---

Interface:

```
public interface IFirstService : IService
{
    OrderDto CreateOrder(Order order);
    Task<string> ProcessOrder(string orderXml);
    void ProcessLineItems(ref List<NewLineItem> items, ref int lineNum, Item i, string orderId);
    NewOrderEvent NewOrderEvent(OrderDto newOrder, Order order, List<NewLineItem> lineItems);
}
```

---

MyFirstService :

```
public class MyFirstService : IFirstService
{
    private SftpService _sftpService;
    private readonly ITimer<MyService> _timer;
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    private readonly ILogger<MyService> _logger;
    private readonly MyFirstConfig _iOptions;

    private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource;

    public MyService(IMediator mediator, ILogger<MyService> logger, IOptionsSnapshot<MyFirstConfig> iOptions)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
        _timer = new Timer<MyFirstService>(logger);
        _logger = logger;
        _iOptions = iOptions.Value;

        CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(FeedStopped);
    }

    private void CreateSftpService()
    {
        _sftpService = new SftpService(_iOptions.SftpOptions);
    }

    public void StartFeed()
    {
        CreateSftpService();
        StartFeed(TimerSchedule);
    }

    public void StartFeed(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        _timer.ScheduleCallback(timeSpan, ProcessOrderFeedAsync, CancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    public void StopFeed()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        _sftpService.Dispose();
    }
```

---

Startup:

```
services.Configure<MyFirstConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("FirstSection"));
services.Configure<MySecondConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("SecondSection"));

services.AddSingleton<IFirstService, MyFirstService>();
services.AddSingleton<ISecondService, MySecondService>();

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFirstService>().StartFeed();
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISecondService>().StartFeed();
```

---

Controller: (I do handle other status codes, I stripped out the try/catch as they are irrelevant)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SFTP.Services;
using System;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("feeds/start")]
        public IActionResult StartFeed([FromServices] IFirstService myService)
        {
            myService.StartFeed();
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("feeds/stop")]
        public IActionResult StopFeed([FromServices] IFirstService myService)
        {
            myService.StopFeed();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything obvious here. Have you got an errant `AddScoped` or `AddTransient` for `ISubService` _after_ the call to `AddSingleton`?

Comment: @Mayo I added start feed in, it creates a local copy of `sftpService` which is disposed of when `stopFeed()` is called

Comment: @KirkLarkin I don't think so but I will go through the startup again and pay close attention to Scoped or Transient assignments

Comment: If you want a long-running service you should register it as a *background* hosted service. Check [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class). How did you determine that the constructor is called twice though? There's no logging in the constructor

Comment: How do you know it is a different instance?  Try setting private field using a GUID and inspecting that field while debugging to see if it actually is a different instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that a service provider was being generated and used to start the feeds as part of configure services so that when the dependency injection was resolving itself a new instantiation was being forced.

I have moved the logic in to the `Configure()` method and `IApplicationBuilder` now handles starting the feeds to generate the instance of each service:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MyFirstConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("Next"));
    services.Configure<MySecondConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("CustomGateway"));

    services.AddSingleton<IFirstService, MyFirstService>();
    services.AddSingleton<ISecondService, MySecondService>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IFirstService>().StartFeed();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not intended as an answer (hence community wiki). However, I felt this was important, nonetheless, and wouldn't be possible to cover clearly via a comment.

You should not inject `IConfiguration` into a service like this. That creates a tight coupling between your configuration and the service, both the method of obtaining the configuration (`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`) and magic strings like `MySection`. If the format of the config should change, your service will break, because it's depending on things (both the knowledge that there's a `MySection` section in the config, and how that config is retrieved) that it shouldn't actually know anything about.

Instead, you should always just inject the information you actually require, i.e. the values of `Host`, `Username`, `Password`, etc. When there's a lot of tokens like this, you might instead consider creating an options class to encapsulate them, and then inject that instead. For example:

```
public class SftpServiceOptions
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then, you can even use the options pattern to bind the values easily from your config:

```
services.Configure<SftpServiceOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MySection"));
```

Now, the magic string is in your app setup instead of some random service, making it much more obvious and easier to track down, should it ever change.

Comment: Thanks for that I never knew there was anything like `IOptionsMonitor` / `IOptionsSnapshot` I've changed my code a wee bit to cater for that... Found my issue anyway - Will self answer shortly.